# Moved to a new Mac and now GCC is missing, what to do?

Tags: macos, xcode, gcc

I have a new Macbook. I bought it, use time machine to move to it, and it copied everything and xCode runs fine, but when I go to the terminal and type gcc it says command not found.

How do I get GCC ?

Comment: What version of Mac OS X and Xcode?

Comment: Lion and the latest version of xCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcc` is in `/Developer/usr/bin` and `/usr/bin`. Check these directories and the value of your `PATH` environment variable, and add to it as needed.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: What specifically?

Answer (score 3):

With the latest Xcode, you first need to "Install Command Line Tools." Open XCode.  Under the XCode tab, open Preferences, click on the Download panel, and click the install button next to CLI Tools to manually download the XCode CLI Tools.

Once you do that, `gcc` will be in `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the ultimate answer is: Get used to `clang`.

According to [this discussion at Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=1160509) and [this email from the Glascow Haskell Compiler mailing list](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/glasgow-haskell-users/2011-October/020998.html), `gcc` is no longer distributed with Xcode 4.2 and `clang` is the new default, with `llvm-gcc` provided so that developers can port to `clang`.

You might also find answers to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765157/use-gcc-4-2-in-xcode-4-2-and-ios-sdk-5-0) useful.

Comment: `gcc` is a symlink to `llvm-gcc`, and should still be available.

Comment: I need GCC, not clang or anything else. How can I get this on Mac?

Comment: If you need real GCC, I think you'll have to install from MacPorts or similar.  If you're writing Mac software, Apple's already told you it's on the way out as far as they're concerned.

Comment: I'm writing software that will be compiled and tested on Linux environments but I need GCC to compile and test within my Local Machine.